# Override the padding and margins in a container

Tags: html, css, overriding, padding

I have a certain point in the page where I want this section to be 100% width of container div. As you can see on the picture below, The white space to left is padding, an attribute to the .article-wrapper-pro, basically I want this to be overridden so there is no padding?

[image: Padding]

Code:

```
<div class="article-wrapper-pro">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 medium-8 columns about-border">
      <article class="padd">
        <h3 class="about-intro">YADDA YADDDA YADDA</h3>
        <p>YADDA YADDDA YADDAYADDA YADDDA YADDAYADDA YADDDA YADDAYADDA YADDDA YADDAYADDA YADDDA YADDA</p>
        <p>YADDA YADDDA YADDAYADDA YADDDA YADDAYADDA YADDDA YADDA</p>
        <h2>Take a look</h2>
        <div class="about-images">
          <img src="img/oakview-screen.jpg" alt="e" </img>
        </div>
      </article>
      <div class="work-with-us">
        <h2 class="about-serv">Work with us</h2>
        <p>IYADDA YADDDA YADDAYADDA YADDDA YADDA</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="medium-4 columns about-images show-for-medium-up project-side">
      <img class="project-logos" src="img/oakview-logo.jpg" alt="Oak View Logo" </img>
      <div class="side-section">
        <h3 class="about-side-headings">Services</h3>
        <div class="about-list-side">
          <ul>
            <li>YADDA YADDDA YADDA</li>
            <li>YADDA YADDDA YADDA</li>
            <li>YADDA YADDDA YADDA</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <h3 class="about-side-headings">YADDA YADDDA YADDA</h3>
        <div class="about-list-side">
          <ul>
            <li>YADDA YADDDA YADDA</li>
            <li>YADDA YADDDA YADDA</li>
            <li>YADDA YADDDA YADDA</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use negative margin.

Think of the following scenario:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box-to-override">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    width: 500px;
    background: red;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-top: 100px; /* Only to demonstrate */
}

.box-to-override {
    margin-left: -40px;
    background: #CCC;
    min-height: 300px; /* Only to demonstrate */;
}
```

The `margin-left` in the `.box-to-override` class makes the div expand over the padding set in `.container`.

Here's the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ftzanae3/)

Comment: I had a similar problem where I wanted to have a centered header but with differing page margins for left and right. The negative margin for the header helped offset the difference in the page margins.